# FIND RECORDS WHOSE DATES ARE OVERLAPPING WITH EACH OTHER

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

How can i find the records whose date range are overlapping. Please look into the following picture.
[image]

```
select memid, enrid, memfirstname, memlastname,
       gender, dob, relflag, udfc5, effdate,
       termdate, lvlid5, lvldesc5, lvlid6, lvldesc6
  from zzz_temp
  where memid = '012345'
  order by effdate, termdate;
```

I have selected one member(SUJAN SHRESTHA) from the table ZZZ_TEMP as an example. There are more than millions members in this table. I want to find such records whose date range are overlapping within a member.
In above picture, effdate and termdate denotes starting and ending dates respectively. 
Records 1 and 2 have same effdate and termdate which are overlapping with records 3 and 4 by 1 month 20 days.
I need to find these 1st four records only. All other records will be excluded as effdate is greater than termdate.

query i have tried.

```
select t1.*
  from zzz_temp t1
  join t zzz_temp t2 
    on (t1.effdate  > t2.effdate  and t1.effdate  < t2.termdate) or 
       (t1.termdate > t2.effdate  and t1.termdate < t2.termdate) or 
       (t1.termdate > t2.termdate and t1.effdate  < t2.effdate);
```

But this didn't work. Can anyone help me figure this.

Comment: When posting data, code, or in fact **anything** in a question please include it as **text** rather than as an image. People can work with text fairly easily, but people are not going to re-type data from your image so they can work with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To check for overlaps you check for table 2's end_date being greater than table 1's start_date and table 2's start_date is less than table 2's end date. That would make your query like:

```
select *
from   zzz_temp t1
       inner join zzz_temp t2 
         on t1.memid = t2.memid
            and t2.end_date > t1.start_date
            and t2.start_date < t1.end_date;
```

You may or may not wish to convert one or both of those inequalities to include an equality (e.g. `t2.end_date <= t1.start_date`) depending on what counts as an overlap for you.

Comment: I think that we also have to check if `memid`s are the same and if rows are different, something like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4ae4ab4bf536b8b5f439be55553ef1e2) (in <= version).

Comment: Yes, true; I didn't see the where clause in the original query, somehow!